# SQL Server doesn't accept fraction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SQL Server doesn't accept the decimal. How do I make this happen? It doesn't accept the 0.9

```
SELECT TOP (250000 * 0.9 / 100) 
    [FIRST], [MIDDLE], [LAST], [PHONE], [ADDRESS], [CITY], [STATE]
FROM 
    [7.Exporting].[dbo].[table1]
```

Error is

> The number of rows provided for a TOP or FETCH clauses row count parameter must be an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an expression.  Just remove the decimal point:

```
select TOP (250000*9/1000) . . .
```

Or, have an explicit `cast()`:

```
selectTOP (cast(250000*0.9/1000 as int)) . . .
```

I'm rather surprised this works, but it seems to.

Comment: Surprising @Gordon is good for a +1 on both the question and the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`top` works only for integer

```
SELECT TOP (any int value) [FIRST],[MIDDLE],[LAST],[PHONE],[ADDRESS],[CITY],[STATE]
      FROM [7.Exporting].[dbo].[table1]
```